# XmlSerializer, There was an error generating the XML document

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, xml-serialization

```
        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Objects.PIP>));

        **MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(new byte[1024]);**

        formatter.Serialize(stream, Repository.GlobalRepository.PIPInformation);

        byte[] bt = stream.ToArray();
        foreach (Communication.Client Client in server.ClientList)
        {
            Client.SendMessage(bt);
            
        }
        stream.Flush();
```

I get an error in stared line as:

> There was an error generating the XML document.
>
> InnerException {"Memory stream is not expandable."}

```
PIP Class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ObjectLibrary.Model;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace PIPServer.Objects
{

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:my-namespace")]
public class PIP
{
    private long pipID;

    public long PipID
    {
        get { return pipID; }
        set { pipID = value; }
    }

    private CurrencyPair currencyPair;

    public CurrencyPair CurrencyPair
    {
        get { return currencyPair; }
        set { currencyPair = value; }
    }
    ...............
 }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?
Also is my method to convert Stream to byte array correct?  [Answered]

Comment: It's most likely something else in your PIP class. Please give us the full class definition

Comment: there are just other properties nothing else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MemoryStream` has a `ToArray()` method that you can use. It returns a byte array with the entire contents of the stream. Just make sure you are finished writing to the stream before reading the contents. :-)

As for the error, it is hard to answer without more information. Have you verified that all the objects you try to serialize are valid?

**Edit:**

From your comments I think I know what the problem is. You define the `MemoryStream` with a fixed size of 1024 bytes. When you serialize your object the generated xml is larger than that and you end up with an error saying you cannot expand the memory stream. Try to create it without setting an explicit size (just use

> new MemoryStream()

), or set a larger size.

Also, if you don't want to serialize a property, just tag it with the `XmlIgnore` attribute.

Comment: there is a inner object CurrencyPair do i need to serialize the too. and also i dont want to save that object who can i ignore that.

Comment: Inner Exception {"Memory stream is not expandable."}

Answer (score 2):

With your update to include the inner exception, it becomes clear: since you are initializing the MemoryStream with a fixed-size byte array, the entire XML must fit in your 1024 bytes. It sounds like you have enough properties to make that a problem.

Did you really mean for a maximum of 1024 bytes, or were did you intend to set an initial size capacity for the stream. The latter would be:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(1024);
```